# Exclude values existing in a list that contains words like

Tags: python, regex, pandas, list, fasttext

I have a list of merchant category:

```py
[
  'General Contractors–Residential and Commercial', 
  'Air Conditioning, Heating and Plumbing Contractors', 
  'Electrical Contractors', 
  ...., 
  'Insulation, Masonry, Plastering, Stonework and Tile Setting Contractors'
]
```

I want to exclude merchants from my dataframe if `df['merchant_category'].str.contains()` any of such merchant categories.

However, I cannot guarantee that the value in my dataframe has the long name as in the list of merchant category. It could be that my dataframe value is just `air conditioning`.

As such, `df = df[~df['merchant_category'].isin(list_of_merchant_category)]` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can collect a long list of positive examples (categories you definitely want to keep), & negative examples (categories you definitely want to exclude), you could try to train a *text classifier* on that data.

It would then be able to look at new texts and make a reasonable guess as to whether you want them included or excluded, based on their similarity to your examples.

So, as you're working in Python, I suggest you look for online tutorials and examples of "binary text classification" using Scikit-Learn.

While there's a bewildering variety of possible approaches to both representing/vectorizing your text, and then learning to make classifications from those vectors, you may have success with some very simple ones commonly used in intro examples. For example, you could represent your textual categories with bag-of-words and/or character-n-gram (word-fragments) representations. Then try  NaiveBayes or SVC classifiers (and others if you need to experiment for possibly-bettr results).

Some of these will even report a sort of 'confidence' in their predictions - so you could potentially accept the strong predictions, but highlight the weak predictions for human review. When a human then looks at, an definitively rules on, a new 'category' string – because it was highlighted an iffy prediction, or noticed as an error, you can then improve the overall system by:

- adding that to the known set that are automatically included/excluded based on an exact literal comparison
- re-training the system, so that it has a better chance at getting other new similar strings correct

(I know this is a very high-level answer, but once you've worked though some attempts based on other intro tutorials, and hit issues with your data, you'll be able to ask more specific questions here on SO to get over any specific issues.)